# How to retrieve the scrolling direction for LazyRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

For a `LazyRow`, or `Column`, how to I know whether the user has scrolled left or right ( or up or... you know). We do not need callbacks in compose for stuff like that, since `mutableStateOf` objects always anyway trigger recompositions so I just wish to know a way to store it in a variable. Okay so there's `lazyRowState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset`, which can be used to mesaure it in a way, but I can't find a way to store its value first, and then subtract the current value to retrieve the direction (based on positive or negative change). Any ideas on how to do that, thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in function to get this info from `LazyListState`.

You can use something like:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
            } else {
                previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }.also {
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

Then just use `listState.isScrollingUp()` to get the info about the scroll.

This snippet is  used in a google [codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/AnimationCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelab/animation/ui/home/Home.kt#L339).

Comment: Would that not be triggered only upon reaching a specific offset? I mean when the scroll offset reaches a specific portion, then only does the firstVisibleItemIndex change (I think it does when the current first item is scrolled completely off the screen.) I mean if the padding between the items themselves is around 15 DPs, and I scroll by 5 dp to the right, it won't be recorded here. Check out my answer above, it uses the offset property instead of index, so it should give continuos updates, and hey isn't the latest version `1.0.1`?

Comment: Oh wait! It's perfect! Didn't see the conditional logic. Thanks!

Comment: Anything wrong with my implementation below by the way? Seems kinda simpler

Answer (score 2):

Got it

```
{ //Composable Scope
val lazyRowState = rememberLazyListState()
    val pOffset = remember { lazyRowState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset }
    val direc = lazyRowState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - pOffset
    val scrollingRight /*or Down*/ = direc > 0 // Tad'aa
}
```

Comment: I was playing with this a bit. I was not sure, but now I know that the scrolloffset is a per-item value, so it resets when you cross to boundary to the next item. Which means that this will give false reads when crossing the item boundary. Means you have to take both into acccount, item and offset.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, seems reasonable (TLDR tho, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

This extensions functions can be very handy for you:

```
fun LazyListState.isFirstItemVisible() = firstVisibleItemIndex == 0

@Composable
fun LazyListState.isScrollingDown(): Boolean {
    val offset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) { derivedStateOf { (firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - offset) > 0 } }.value
}

@Composable
fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    val offset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) { derivedStateOf { (firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - offset) < 0 } }.value
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to false positives when the `firstVisibleItemIndex` is changed, I ended up with the following version:

```
@Composable
fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousItemIndex by remember(this) { mutableIntStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableIntStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    var scrollingUp by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(true) }

    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousItemIndex == firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                scrollingUp = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - previousScrollOffset <= 0
            } else {
                previousItemIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
            }

            previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset

            scrollingUp
        }
    }.value
}
```

The scroll state is cached and preserved while `firstVisibleItemIndex` is changed.