Android how to control item animation direction? RecyclerView + LazyColumn
i want to know how to achieve list item animation like this (video here)?
in the video, the animation is quite special, generally speaking, if you scroll up the list, the item animation is downwards, and if you scroll down the list, the item animation is upwards.
in the video, the item animation indeed has an exact direction, including the expanding animation(the item height grows) and the inserting animation(more and more items becoming visible).

You can detect scroll direction and apply animation to LazyColumn's item accordingly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68731559/11512499

@AdnanHabib that seems impossible because animation doesn't work in lazycolumn

Can you please attach code and exact problem you are facing with animation in your question?

@AdnanHabib AnimatedVisibility in items{} doesn't work, only Modifier.animateItemPlacement() on item works
